# How can I delete a letter from a string in a list?

Tags: python

I have to solve the following problem:
-Write a program that takes a text as an entry and prints the same text without the letter 'r' in it.The teacher said that we have to use a list to put all the words in it and then remove the letter "r" from them. Here is how I started:

```
 text = input("Enter some text: ")
 l=text.split(" ")
 for i in range(len(l)): #I want to use for to run the elements of the list
```

I don't know what to do next and what method I should use, I thought maybe the method remove() can be useful,but I don't know how to use it in each item of the list.

Comment: There is `str.replace`. Just replace the "r" by nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO,

Here is my version.

```
statement = input("Enter some text: ")
listOfWords = statement.split(" ")
for i, word in enumerate(listOfWords):
    if("r" in word.lower()):
        print("found an instance of letter r in the word ({0})".format(word))
        listOfWords[i]=word.replace("r", "")

sentence = " ".join(listOfWords)
print(sentence)
```

First - it grabs all the words from the input text as a list. 
Then it iterates over all the words and if there is a "r" , it removes it from the word and updates the list as well. At the every end it generates the sentense back from the list.

Please note - this is ultra verbose code. It does not use Python features like List Comprehension, but it is much easier to understand. I purposefully added debug statements.

Please let me know if this works for you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the list: str.split() will give a list of each item surrounded with whitespace (You can specify any delimiter you like)

Let's start with an individual list item... We will go with "Rollercoaster".

We can use the `in` keyword to check if a substring included in a larger string.

```
text = input("Enter some text: ")
result = ""
for ch in text.lower():
    if ch == 'r':
        continue
    else:
        result += ch
print(result)
```

Returns

```
Enter some text: rollercoster
ollecoste

Process finished with exit code 0
```